# Safari removes form tags

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, safari, underscore.js

Safari is removing the first instance of the beginning and end form tags from the DOM from a backbone.js app. The innerHTML is unaffected! Firefox has no issues at all with my code and performs perfectly. The code is inserted into the DOM from a script/template file using underscore.

```
<form id="i-get-removed" action="#">
   <div>This content here does not get removed no matter what!!!</div>
</form>

<form id="I-do-not-get-removed-but-I-would-if-the-above-form-was-not-there" action="#">
.
</form>
```

Here's what the safari web inspector shows after the container is rendered:

```
<div>This content here does not get removed no matter what!!!</div>

<form id="I-do-not-get-removed-but-I-would-if-the-above-form-was-not-there" action="#">
.
</form>
```

I'm absolutely beside myself with this - I couldn't imagine a way to make this happen if I wanted to.  I would greatly appreciate any insight into this insanity!

Comment: Pasting `<form id="foo"></form>` shows the form is in the HTML, even if it's the only element in the body.

Answer (score 1):

A form nested within a form will cause this behavior in Safari.